# redmine error with RMagic

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

Hello now i am install redmine but when i try migrate my database there is a error :

```
[DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
```

there is stacktrce :

```
 root@server:/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0# bundle exec rake db:migrate
[DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:211:in `resolve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:139:in `resolve'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/opt/redmine/redmine-3.0/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong place of the log. You have error in DB settings: `ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]`. `RMagick` is just a deprecation warning

Comment: Gotva is right. You may ignore the deprecation warning, but you need to specify a development database, or launch the server in production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While performing bundler actions like the above, you have to always specify environment, unless it's added to your system or shell's environment vars, like ~/.bashrc on linux or environment variables under windows, so in your command, you should add RAILS_ENV=production, and your command would look like this:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```